# PHP how do I create a list of all tasks

Tags: php, echo

Alright, I have a table of tasks this table has a foreign key which is the "projectID"

I am selecting all the rows within that table that have the same projectID. But I now want to output the results in a list ("`<li></li>`")

```
//Select tasks
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE projectID = '".$project_ID."'";
$result5 = $db->sql_query($sql);
$data5 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result5);
```

[image]

Comment: You didn't do any research effort. What you want is almost in the man page of [mysql_fetch_assoc](http://fr2.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) and can be found in [many](http://www.yourwebskills.com/mysqllists.php) [tutorials](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp). You did not even tag your question well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need to iterate through each of the rows and output the taskList column value:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE projectID = '".$project_ID."'";
$result5 = $db->sql_query($sql);

$data5 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result5);
// this will let you handle an empty result set without a count.
if( $data5 )
{
    // opening the list only if there are things to put there
    echo "<ul >";
    do
    {
        // output the value from one row.
        echo "<li>" . $data5['taskName'].'</li>';
    }while($data5 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result5));
    echo "</ul>";
}
else
{ 
    echo 'No tasks found!';
}
```

Comment: I am getting this error.
Notice: Undefined index: taskName in C:\wamp\www\cvlFree
\PRINT_workOrderLastEntered.php on line 199

Comment: There were two bugs: $data['tastName'] should have been $data['taskName'], and there should have been a `.` in front of it

Comment: i had actually fixed those already. And still getting the error.

Comment: figured it out. It needed to be changed to  $data5['taskName']